# Write a program to accept number from command line and display sum of digits in a number by using recursive funcion

Tags: java

I have written the code but it displays Stackoverflowerror message.

```
class Sum
{
     int ans=0,temp,temp2;
     int  getsum(int no)
     {
          if(no>0)
          {
              temp=no % 10;
              ans=ans + temp;
              getsum(no/10); 
          }
          else
          {
              return ans;
          }
     }
}


class recsum
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          Sum s=new Sum();
          int no,len;
          len=args.length;

           if(len==0)
           {
               System.out.println("No argruments are given ! ");
           }
           else
           {
               no=Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
               System.out.println("Sum of digits= " + s.getsum(no));
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Can you provide us with what you have so far? Is this homework?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile.  Every execution path of `getsum` needs to return an `int`.  Please copy and paste the code you're executing and post the exact input you're providing and the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

You are over-complicating things a lot in your code. Here is a simpler working example:

```
public static int getSum(final String[] args, final int index) {
  if (index < args.length) {
    return Integer.valueOf(args[index]) + getSum(args, index + 1);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("You need to provide numbers as arguments.");
  }
  final int sum = getSum(args, 0);
  System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
}
```

- You are supposed to be recursive, this is in the getSum function, because it is calling itself with differing parameters.
- In recursive functions, you always need to have an exit branch that causes the calling to stop.
- As sums won't change if you add 0 this can be exploited for a very clean exit.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack overflow is normally because you never bottom out of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Change class Sum to this:

```
class Sum {
    int ans = 0, temp = 0;
    int getsum(int no) {
        if((no/10)-.5 >= 1)
            ans += getsum(no/10);
        else
            return ans;
    }
}
```

I'm not completely sure if this will work, and I can't compile it right now. I think this is one way to do it, but again, I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Program: Write a program to use Command Line Arguments.

```
class Sumnum1
{  
    int i,t,num,sum=0;

    void getData(String s)
    {
       num=Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

    int digitSum()
    {
       for(i=num;i>=1;i=i/10)
       {
           t=i%10;
           sum=sum+t;
       }
      return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        int ds=0;

        Sumnum1 obj=new Sumnum1(); 
        obj.getData(arg[0]);
        ds=obj.digitSum();
        System.out.println("sum of digit="+ds);
     }
}
```

BY :ANKIT AGRAWAL (A.A.)